# Unable to run code through Galvanize text editor

Tags: python

I am currently working on a practice problem through the Galvanize workshop for Python as a beginner programmer and I came across a problem. Unfortunately I do not know where the problem is occurring.

Here is the question:

**Write a function called is_it_five_or_three that takes a number as input, and returns True if that number is 5 or if that number is 3. If the number is neither 3 or 5, the function should return False.**

And here is the code I wrote below:

```
x = int(input('Enter a number: '))

def is_it_five_or_three(x):
    if x == 5:
        return True

    elif x == 3:
        return True

    else:
        return False


print(is_it_five_or_three (x))
```

When I run the code through Pycharm the code runs perfectly (true for input of 3 or 5 and false for all other numbers) but when I enter it into the text editor that Galvanize provides it gives me an error. Does anyone know what might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is the error for reference:

````
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_methods (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_methods
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/src/app/test_methods.py", line 6, in <module>
    import main
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = int(input('Enter a number: '))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line```


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
````

Comment: The error is because you are using the `input` function to grab input in an environment that doesn't allow that, so when `input` tries to read a line, it gets an EOF (end of file).  Did the galvanize workshop say specifically to use the `input` function here?